# Vertical alignment of the `aligned` environment in table cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, best-practices

I think most people will agree that the vertical alignment in the table cells below is less than ideal--especially if I want to remove the `\cmidrule` to be more in line with accepted "best practices" for tables.
[image]
What I'd like is the following: For every cell in the lower two rows of the table, the content should be flush with the top of the cell.  (Possible exception: I'm not entirely convinced this is right for the leftmost column.)  The headings E1|C, etc. should remain vertically centered.

Important note: ideally, all the columns except the leftmost column should have their width determined automatically. I would prefer not to have to specify the width of a `parbox` or similar (although if you can solve it using these, that is still better than I have been able to do so far).

I'm sure the solution to this is contained somewhere in the labyrinth of related questions, but...well...the related questions are a labyrinth, and I was unable to find what I was looking for.

Here's the code for this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\newcommand*{\sheaf}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright}m{10.5em} l l l l@{}}
\toprule
Rational curve: \\$[t,s] \mapsto$ & $\sheaf E_{1} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{3} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{4} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{5} |_C$ 
\\ \midrule 
$[-s t^{8}+2s^{8} t+2s^{9},\linebreak[0]-s^{4} t^{5},\linebreak[0]s^{5} t^{4}-s^{9},\linebreak[0]2t^{9}-s^{9}]$ 
& $\begin{aligned}&\sheaf O(-3)^{3}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}&\sheaf O(-2)^{8}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{11}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}&\sheaf O(-2)^{3}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{30}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}&\sheaf O(-1)^{45}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{10}\end{aligned}$ 
%
\\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
%
$[s t^{8}-s^{2} t^{7},\linebreak[0]2t^{9}-s^{8} t,\linebreak[0]-s^{9},\linebreak[0]t^{9}]$ 
& $\begin{aligned}&\sheaf O(-6)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}&\sheaf O(-4)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-3)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)^{4}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{12}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}&\sheaf O(-3)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)^{4}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{25}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{4}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}&\sheaf O(-2)^{3}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{39}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{13}\end{aligned}$ 
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `t` for the optional argument of `aligned` to get top alignment; I also changed the first column to be of type `p{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\newcommand*{\sheaf}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{10.5em} l l l l@{}}
\toprule
Rational curve: \\$[t,s] \mapsto$ & $\sheaf E_{1} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{3} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{4} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{5} |_C$ 
\\ \midrule 
$[-s t^{8}+2s^{8} t+2s^{9},\linebreak[0]-s^{4} t^{5},\linebreak[0]s^{5} t^{4}-s^{9},\linebreak[0]2t^{9}-s^{9}]$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-3)^{3}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{8}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{11}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{3}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{30}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-1)^{45}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{10}\end{aligned}$ 
%
\\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
%
$[s t^{8}-s^{2} t^{7},\linebreak[0]2t^{9}-s^{8} t,\linebreak[0]-s^{9},\linebreak[0]t^{9}]$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-6)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-4)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-3)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)^{4}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{12}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-3)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)^{4}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{25}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{4}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{3}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{39}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{13}\end{aligned}$ 
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a `\parbox` for the first entry of the first row, gives vertically centered entries for the row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\newcommand*{\sheaf}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{10.5em} l l l l@{}}
\toprule
\parbox{10.5em}{Rational curve: \\$[t,s] \mapsto$} & $\sheaf E_{1} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{3} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{4} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{5} |_C$ 
\\ \midrule 
$[-s t^{8}+2s^{8} t+2s^{9},\linebreak[0]-s^{4} t^{5},\linebreak[0]s^{5} t^{4}-s^{9},\linebreak[0]2t^{9}-s^{9}]$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-3)^{3}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{8}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{11}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{3}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{30}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-1)^{45}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{10}\end{aligned}$ 
%
\\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
%
$[s t^{8}-s^{2} t^{7},\linebreak[0]2t^{9}-s^{8} t,\linebreak[0]-s^{9},\linebreak[0]t^{9}]$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-6)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-4)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-3)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)^{4}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{12}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-3)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)^{4}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{25}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{4}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{3}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{39}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{13}\end{aligned}$ 
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally, I would opt for the first option (everything top aligned).

Perhaps you could also use aligned environments on the first column too to get a little more spacing between the consecutive lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\newcommand*{\sheaf}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{10.5em} l l l l@{}}
\toprule
Rational curve: \\$[t,s] \mapsto$ & $\sheaf E_{1} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{3} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{4} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{5} |_C$ 
\\ \midrule 
$\begin{aligned}[t]
&[-s t^{8}+2s^{8} t+2s^{9},\\[-0.65ex]
&-s^{4} t^{5}, s^{5} t^{4}-s^{9}, \\[-0.65ex]
&2t^{9}-s^{9}]
\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-3)^{3}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{8}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{11}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{3}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{30}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-1)^{45}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{10}\end{aligned}$ 
%
\\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
%
$\begin{aligned}[t]
&[s t^{8}-s^{2} t^{7},2t^{9}-s^{8} t, \\[-0.65ex]
& -s^{9}, t^{9}]
\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-6)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-4)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-3)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)^{4}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{12}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-3)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)^{4}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{25}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{4}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{3}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{39}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{13}\end{aligned}$ 
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `tabularx` package, you can avoid having to guess the right width for the first column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx}

\newcommand*{\sheaf}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright}X l l l l@{}}
\toprule
Rational curve: \\$[t,s] \mapsto$ & $\sheaf E_{1} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{3} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{4} |_C$ & $\sheaf E_{5} |_C$ 
\\ \midrule 
$[-s t^{8}+2s^{8} t+2s^{9},\linebreak[0]-s^{4} t^{5},\linebreak[0]s^{5} t^{4}-s^{9},\linebreak[0]2t^{9}-s^{9}]$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-3)^{3}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{8}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{11}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{3}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{30}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-1)^{45}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{10}\end{aligned}$ 
%
\\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
%
$[s t^{8}-s^{2} t^{7},\linebreak[0]2t^{9}-s^{8} t,\linebreak[0]-s^{9},\linebreak[0]t^{9}]$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-6)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-4)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-3)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)^{4}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{12}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-3)\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-2)^{4}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{25}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{4}\end{aligned}$ 
& $\begin{aligned}[t]&\sheaf O(-2)^{3}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O(-1)^{39}\\ &\oplus \sheaf O^{13}\end{aligned}$ 
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You also need to put a `parbox` around the contents of row 1 column 1, in order to make keep the headings vertically centered once you've changed the `m` to `p`. However, I consider this "legal" since there's no good way to get around artificially imposing the width of the first column.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Ah, then perhaps I misunderstood part of your request. I thought everything should be aligned on top. Do you want the first column content to be vertically centered?

Comment: I see your point about entries of the first column being a bit crowded vertically, but the real tables I'm making include several pages worth of computer-generated examples, and breaking all the lines by hand is not practical.  (On the other hand, programming my computer to output `\linebreak[0]` after every comma is quite easy.)

Comment: I want every row to be aligned on top except the top row, which should be vertically centered. (Although you are free to persuade me otherwise.)

Comment: @CharlesStaats I personally prefer everything top aligned, but this is a matter of taste and, as such, relative. In any case, I added to my answer an option with the first row with centered vertical alignment.

Comment: @CharlesStaats I added another option, in the last code of my answer, using the `tabularx` package to avoid manual calculations.

Comment: This adds a slight complication, since in the real tables, I'm using `longtable`. Still, it's a very nice thought.

Comment: @CharlesStaats the [ltxtable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) package combines `tabularx` and `longtable`.